# Python fileinput delete lines

Tags: python-3.5

I have a csv file that looks like following:

```
CCC, rev, pIndex, no.
23, 2.5, 0, 4
34, 4.3, 1, 3
27, 7.9, 2, 5
12, 5.7, 3, 7
```

where the third element in each line is called the `pIndex`. I have code that replicates each line once, while updating the `pIndex` accordingly. So the output looks like following:

```
CCC, rev, pIndex, no.
23, 2.5, 0, 4
23, 2.5, 1, 4
34, 4.3, 2, 3
34, 4.3, 3, 3
27, 7.9, 4, 5
27, 7.9, 5, 5
12, 5.7, 6, 7
12, 5.7, 7, 7
```

Below is the code that does that:

```
with fileinput.input(inplace=True) as f:
    n = 0
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        numbers = line.split(sep = ',')
        for i in range(2):
            numbers[3] = n
            n += 1
            s = ''
            for j in numbers:
                s += str(j) + ','
            s = s.rstrip(',')
            print(s)
```

Now I want to delete one duplication each of the first and last line, so basically delete the first line (after header, with `pIndex 0`) and the last line in the file. I am using `fileinput` and trying to write the result back in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

While reading in the lines you could store them in an array and leave out the ones you want to delete. Then write the array to the file.

You can write to csv using the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) for example like this:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried `result = []` `result.append(s)` `result = result[1:-1]`, but it just prints a blank array in each line

Comment: Can you show me the complete code with the array added? Did you try the csv writer?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/AnanDvd/MPI-Pigino/commit/e7972209e4740b7747e47f06895f568e766506c7) is the link to the code. I am trying to make it general for a lot of files, so that I can run it from the cmd line like `python3 script.py file.csv`